# TableViewのCellを任意のタイミングで追加したい

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10

以下のソースでは、起動時に`itemes`にあるものがテーブルのセルに格納されます。
ここに

```
func addCell(){
    //データの追加と追加したデータを元にテーブルビューの更新をしたい
    objects.insert(NSDate(), at: 0)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

のような，関数（これはそのまま`insertNewObject`ですが）をつくって追加したいのですが，objectsにデータが追加されても、実際のテーブルには反映されません。
理想としては`insertNewObject`と`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCella`が走るような動作が出来るといいのでしょうか？

ここを参考にしても出来ません。
http://ameblo.jp/highcommunicate/entry-12059919502.html　より

```
    // セルに新しいデータを追加
    @IBAction func tapAdd(sender: AnyObject) {
        // myItemsに追加.
        myItems.addObject("タイトルNEW")
        // TableViewを再読み込み.
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

そんて
（`func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any)`や， `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCella`を参考にしたが、出来ないが，`tableView`に`add(+)`ボタンを配置し押下したときに上記二つが走る為）

どうしたら追加されるか，ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var objects = [Any]()
    var ccClass = custumClass()

    private let itemes = ["Sleepy", "Sneezy", "Bashful", "Happy",
                          "Doc", "Grumpy", "Dopey", "Thorin", "Dorin","Nori", "Ori",
                          "Balin", "Dwalin", "Fili", "Kili",
                          "Oin", "Gloin", "Bifur", "Bofur", "Bombur"
    ]

    let simpleTableIdentifier = "Cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(insertNewObject(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
        if let split = self.splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }
    }

    func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        objects.insert(NSDate(), at: 0)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

・・・略・・・

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell
            = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier,
                                        for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = itemes[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

・・・略・・・

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結論:これは出来ないようです。この解決策が正しいのかはわかりませんが，期待通りの動作はしてくれる。
したかったのはTableViewと入力の二つのviewをリンクしたかった（入力した後，登録操作でTableViewに追加）
解決策として用いたのは，入力View側からNotificationのpostを行い，受け取ったタイミングで上記'addCell'を呼ぶとTableにCellが追加される。
データの受け渡しにはAppDalegateを用いた。

Answer (score 0):

[UIKit - UITableView - insertRows(at:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows)

こちらの*Discussion*から引用します。

> When this method when is called in an animation block defined by the **beginUpdates()** and **endUpdates()** methods, UITableView defers any insertions of rows or sections until after it has handled the deletions of rows or sections.

この1行に従って、以下のようにコードを書き換えてください。

```
func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    objects.insert(NSDate(), at: 0)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記ソースに追加いたしました。この追加分は、Cellの変更中に他のCell追加削除の処理が走らないように保護するという理解でよろしいでしょうか？上記addCell関数にて，起動時以外の任意のタイミングでCellの追加をする場合は、何が必要でしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。